# Install package git-gutter or git-gutter-fringe conditionally

Tags: use-package

I’m trying to install `git-gutter` or `git-gutter-fringe` depending if I’m running in graphics mode or not. I have an `if` statement for that:

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
    (use-package git-gutter-fringe
      ;; package setup here)
  (use-package git-gutter
    ;; same package setup here))
```

I was trying to do it with

```
(use-package (if (display-graphic-p) git-gutter-fringe git-gutter)
  ;; package setup here)
```

or

```
(let ((package-name (if (display-graphic-p) "git-gutter-fringe" "git-gutter-fringe")))
  (use-package package-name
    ;; package setup here))
```

But none of these succeeds.

The final question is, is it possible to do what I want, or do I have to stay with my current config?

Comment: FWIW this question seems rather odd to me, and perhaps for anyone who tends to open both GUI and terminal Emacs clients at different times to the same long-running server. Even *activating* different libraries for different display types doesn't necessarily make sense to me (I might, over time, view any given buffer in multiple display types), let alone *installing* different libraries. You may (or may not) find it worth considering such scenarios, even if they don't apply to you currently.

Comment: p.s. If you can't figure out why someone might use both types, for me it's a matter of whether I'm connecting to the server locally (in which case the network is fast enough to use GUI clients), or remotely (in which case I've found that the performance benefits of using a terminal client far outweigh any other considerations).

Comment: The whole thing about installing is 100% true; the same thing *almost* can be said about activation; in this case however, the `git-gutter-*` packages author decided to use the same *mode* name for both; so, if I well understand it, he imposes this decision of using only one of these packages at the same time. Hence the 3rd code fragment in my answer. I suppose one could alias/change the mode name of the fringe version, and activate that - or the other - per window type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first try should work? I.e. something like this:

```
(if (display-graphic-p)
   (use-package git-gutter-fringe
     :ensure t
     :init (global-git-gutter-mode))
 (use-package git-gutter
  :ensure t
  :init (global-git-gutter-mode)))
```

---

For your 2nd try, since `use-package` is a macro, the `if` is not evaluated before the "call". This should evaluate it when needed:

```
(let ((package-name (if (display-graphic-p)
                        "git-gutter-fringe"
                      "git-gutter")))
  (eval `(use-package ,package-name
    :ensure t
    :init (global-git-gutter-mode))))
```

---

From my tests, the fringe version also installs `git-gutter`, so there may be other approaches to this. You could simply install both, and *enable* the right mode based on `display-graphic-p`. E.g., I'd use:

```
(use-package git-gutter                                                                                              
  :ensure t                                                                                                          
  :init                                                                                                              
  (when (display-graphic-p)                                                                                          
      (use-package git-gutter-fringe                                                                                 
        :ensure t))                                                                                                  
  (global-git-gutter-mode))
```

For those who don't use `git-gutter*`, both packages use the same mode name, hence the similar code in both situations (only the package names are different).

I'm not a great lisper, so there may be other, smarter & shorter solutions out there.

Comment: Your `let` version is working fine, thank you! I don’t really like my current approach, or your third one because I want to use the same configuration for the two packages (I’m speaking about key bindings, color/icon configuration and such).